# Spring batch Partitioner : How to make a spring boot app having spring batch partitioning functionality share load between nodes per job

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, spring-batch-tasklet, spring-batch-job-monitoring

We have a spring boot application which is designed specifically to handle spring batch jobs. Here we are using spring batch partitioner approach. This approach was chosen as we needed the resumability/restartability of a batch on failure in a single node. Reference : Restarting a job after server crash is not processing the unprocessed data.

Is there a way we can make one job which has to process huge number of records share the load between nodes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a job with a remotely partitioned step where each worker step is assigned a partition of the data and is deployed on a different node.

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/tree/main/spring-batch-samples#remote-partitioning-sample).